# Matrix satisfying $A-I = A^{-1}$

Tags: matrices, golden-ratio

Recall the (infinitely) continued fraction definition of the golden ratio
\begin{align}
\phi = 1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\cdots}}}}}
\end{align}
This is equivalent to the expression
\begin{align}
\phi = 1+\frac{1}{\phi}
\end{align}
Saying that the inverse of $\phi$ is equal to $\phi-1$. Inspired by this fact, consider a square matrix $A$ satisfying:
\begin{align}
A-I = A^{-1}
\end{align}
Does this relationship have any significance?

Comment: What could its eigenvalues be?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown $\lambda x = A x \Leftrightarrow\lambda x = (I+A^{-1})x \Leftrightarrow \lambda x = A^{-1}Ax + A^{-1}x \Leftrightarrow\lambda x = A^{-1}(\lambda x+x)\Leftrightarrow\frac{\lambda+1}{\lambda}x=Ax$ so $\lambda = 1+\frac{1}{\lambda}$. Cool!

Answer (score 4):

$$\begin{align}A-I = A^{-1}\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}A = I + A^{-1}\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}A^2 = A + I\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}A^3 = A^2 + A\end{align}=2A+I$$

$$\begin{align}A^4 = A^3 + A^2\end{align}=3A+2I$$

The pattern is now suggesting, 
$$A^n = F_n A+F_{n-1}I$$ where $F_n$ is the Fibonacci's sequence.

Comment: which is why the simplest (integer) version of $A$ is $$ \left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{array} \right)  $$  Multiply the column vector $(F_n, F_{n-1})^T$ and you get $(F_{n+1}, F_{n})^T$

Comment: @WillJagy Good comment. I have seen that matrix before but I did not connect it to this problem.

Comment: This also has significance when computing $\sum F_n$, since the geometric sum will have $(A - I)^{-1}$ in the denominator.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's worth pointing out we can actually prove Mohammad Riazi-Kermani's
equation

$A^n = F_nA + F_{n - 1}I \tag 1$

by induction, for (1) yields

$A^{n + 1} = AA^n = A( F_nA + F_{n - 1}I) =$
$F_nA^2 + F_{n - 1}A = F_n(I + A) + F_{n - 1}A = (F_n  + F_{n - 1})A + F_nI = F_{n + 1}A + F_nI, \tag 2$

since

$F_{n + 1} = F_n + F_{n - 1}.  \tag 3$

Hmmm . . . curious!

Comment: Excellent. Now we have a good proof for the suggestion.

Comment: @MohammadRiazi-Kermani:  Thank you sir.  Always glad to collaborate with you.  Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

The equation $\phi^2 = \phi+1$ has another solution in the [Perplex Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-complex_number). (They're like Complex Numbers, but with $j^2={^+}1$ instead of ${^-}1$.)

$$\phi = \frac{1\pm j\sqrt5}{2}$$

Perplex Numbers can be modelled by $2\times2$ matrices:

$$a+bj \cong \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ b & a \end{bmatrix}$$

So one matrix of the type you're considering (other than the obvious $\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2} I$) is

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 1/2 & \sqrt5/2 \\ \sqrt5/2 & 1/2 \end{bmatrix}$$